# Objective-C: Can't put primitives in NSDictionary and retrieve them successfully

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber, primitive

I know I can't put them in directly, but I have to convert them to an `NSNumber`, for example.  I am converting them to `NSNumber`s, and then putting them in the dictionary.  I immediately log the keys I'm populating, and they are blank.

Here's an example:

```
- (NSDictionary*) dictionaryFromWrestler
{
    /* 
     * Used ot create a dictionary from the instance of the wrestler
     * Can be used to send and receive wrestlers through notification center
     */
    NSDictionary* dictionary;

    NSNumber* _score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];


    dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstName, @"firstName", lastName, @"lastName", fullName, @"fullName", shortName, @"shortName", team, @"team", seed, @"seed", actualWeight, @"actualWeight", dob, @"dob", club, @"club", hometown, @"hometown", state, @"state", grade, @"grade", extraField, @"extraField",  phone, @"phone", address, @"address", zip, @"zip", record, @"record", gradeAbbr, @"gradeAbbr", twid, @"twid", teamId, @"teamId", position, @"position", _score, @"score", [NSNumber numberWithInt:teamScore], @"teamScore", [NSNumber numberWithInt:period1Score], @"period1Score", [NSNumber numberWithInt:period2Score], "@period2Score", [NSNumber numberWithInt:periods], @"periods", [NSNumber numberWithBool:hasRidingTime], @"hasRidingTime", nil];

NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %@", lastName);
NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %i", score);
NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %@", _score);
NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %d", [[dictionary objectForKey:@"score"] intValue]);
NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"score"]);
NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"lastName"]);

    return dictionary;
}
```

My log looks like this:

```
2012-05-18 17:46:53.117 Wrestling Tools[31509:403] dictionaryFromWrestler Score: Brown
2012-05-18 17:46:53.117 Wrestling Tools[31509:403] dictionaryFromWrestler Score: 2
2012-05-18 17:46:53.117 Wrestling Tools[31509:403] dictionaryFromWrestler Score: 2
2012-05-18 17:46:53.117 Wrestling Tools[31509:403] dictionaryFromWrestler Score: (null)
2012-05-18 17:46:53.117 Wrestling Tools[31509:403] dictionaryFromWrestler Score: (null)
2012-05-18 17:46:53.117 Wrestling Tools[31509:403] dictionaryFromWrestler Score: Brown
```

As you can see, the primitives fail, but the objects work.  What the heck?

Comment: I tested your code ..it works just fine for me...must be a problem with your compiler or something. Try reinstalling xcode if nothing works.

Comment: I've tried this on another computer, and had a friend try it.  In all cases, the dictionary's scores key is null.  The same thing happens with other primitives.  I've built a small project with almost nothing in it, and the same issue exists.  What could this issue be?

Comment: I have found a way to make it work, but it doesn't make any sense to me.  If I make dictionary Mutable, it still doesn't work.  If I also add a [dictionary setObject:_score forKey:@"score"]; it does work.  I do not understand why Mutable would make a difference for this, and I do not understand why setting it independently works where dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: doesn't.  Why? @Chuck any ideas?

Comment: maybe the value changes when you add it to dictionary..but i don't see how ( plus it doesn't make any sense). Try this: instead of score..make another variable and declare it before you make the dictionary, then try adding that (just to see if it works). If it does then something is happening with score outside this method, if it doesn't then it's something wrong with your compiler/libraries, in any case you need to reinstall xcode then (as i said)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `-[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` stops processing its list of arguments when it hits a `nil` value.  This doesn't just mean the literal `nil` you wrote; it's any argument that evaluates to `nil` (because, of course, the method can't tell the difference).

So, surely one of the values in your looong list, prior to `_score`, is `nil` and is thus prematurely truncating the list.  Therefore, the dictionary really doesn't have a key "score".

Comment: you nailed it Ken!  As I was messing around with this last night, i switches to using dictionaryWithObject:forKeys: and saw an error that my objects array was short.  That tipped me off to the nil value issue. I just couldn't post the answer last night due to the 8 hour restriction.

Answer (score 4):

"%@" is the format specifier for objects, but you're getting the number's intValue. You want either `NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %d", [[dictionary objectForKey:@"score"] intValue])` or `NSLog(@"dictionaryFromWrestler Score: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"score"])`.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem.  In the initial post, I had also shown hasRidingTime, which was a BOOL before it was stored in the dictionary as a NSNumber.  I was printing it with an %@, as the NSNumber in the dictionary.  Now, I have updated the code and the log, shooing that both of your suggestions show the same results.